# Does the RSA algorithm use repeated squaring?

Tags: rsa, implementation, modular-arithmetic

Simple question: in order to reduce such huge exponents in modular arithmetic, is repeated squaring used in RSA or is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: The RSA algorithm doesn't use repeated squaring. However, many *implementations* of the RSA private key operation do use implementations of modular exponentiation that do use repeated squaring in one form or another.

Comment: @Henrick Hellström I realise that now thanks, blank moment. Is modular exponentiation the most efficient way to do this though? Are there any other methods which I might want to explore (for a project)?

Comment: See [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is the basic algorithm. Most implementations use the CRT method for a 4x speedup compared to computing $m = c^d \pmod n$.

Comment: And [there are some even more advanced tricks for speed ups](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf) if you know the exponent in advance (for example in the RSA encryption case).